# How to convert many-to-many relation form SQL to mongoDB colllection?

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 table in SQL that have many-to-many relation.The first table "account" have 3 field (AccountId,UserName,Email).The second table "device" have 2 field (DeviceId and DeviceCode) and table "Association" have 4 field (AccountId,DeviceId,LastActivityDate,HasException)

How to convert them to mongoDB.
From suggestion of mongodb.org I embed  collection "Associaton" into device collection and account collection but the  field "LastAccessDate" always was updated every time when my system have new transaction.

-Account collection:
{

"UserName" : "xxx",
  "Email" : 1,

"Association" : [{
      "DeviceId" : "4f45c4b73174ec818148d5c5",
      "LastActivityDate" : "Thu, 23 Feb 2012 11:44:19 GMT +07:00",
      "HasException" : false
    }, {
      "DeviceId" : ObjectId("4f45c5e93174ec818148d5c7"),
      "LastActivityDate" : "Thu, 23 Feb 2012 11:52:05 GMT +07:00",
      "Exception" : null
    }]
}

Device collection:
{

"DeviceCode" : "abcjxhcbxkjcnxkcjhdiofjdojdlkdknd",
  "Associations" : [{
      "AccountId" : "34fdgfdy5676",
      "LastActivityDate" : "02/03/2012",
      "HasException" : false
    }, {
      "AccountId" : "34fdgfdy5dd676",
      "LastActivityDate" : "02/03/2012",
      "HasException" : true
    }],

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see multiple solutions for your problem:

### Seldom updates

To avoid joins, that have to be done client-side in NoSQL databases, put everything into one collection. If you do not update very often, you could do

```
{
   _id,
   LastAccessDate,
   HasException,
   Account : {
        AccountID,
        UserName,
        Email },
   Device : {
        DeviceID,
        DeviceCode }
}
```

This results in duplicate data, but if performance (no joins) comes before memory efficiency, it's probably a suitable solution for you. Since the data is stored multiple times, updates are more demanding for the server. I.e. updating the Email address would look like

```
db.myColl.update({"Account.UserName" : "User ToUpdate"}, {"$set" : {"Account.Email" : "new@email.com"} });
```

As you don't need the AccountID and DeviceID to join anymore, you can also drop these two fields.

### Frequent updates

When you have frequent updates, instead of embedding, you could use References. I think you have to resolve them client-side. You then have three collections:

**Account:**

```
{
  _id,
  UserName,
  Email
}
```

**Device:**

```
{
  _id,
  DeviceCode
}
```

**Association:**

```
{
  _id,
  account : {
        "$ref" : "Account",
        "$id" : ... }
  device : {
        "$ref" : "Device",
        "$id" : ... }
}
```

You don't have any duplication this way, but you have to deal with references.